# rsync remove-source-files, how does it resume after killed process?

Tags: backup, rsync, ubuntu-14.04, safe-remove

I'm using rsync with remove-source-files option as follows:

```
rsync --remove-source-files -arzvv --append /src /dst
```

But for some reason it fails(  broken connection or OS kill its process), I would like to know how well it recovers/resume the failure file transfers if I run it again? Is it possible that my data has been deleted before transferring to the new destination?

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305913/rsync-remove-source-files-how-does-it-resume).

Answer (score 0):

From the rsync man:

> --remove-source-files
>
> This  tells  rsync  to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on  the receiving side.

So it seems that a file is deleted on the source side only if it is marked as successfully transferred by rsync.

In my experience Rsync seems to be very friendly with being killed, when this happens I just run the same command and rsync is everytime able to start where he left without any side effect.

The only problem I can find to rerun a killed rsync command with your options is the --append one. I advise you to read the --append and the --append-verify sections of the manual and consider a check for the consistency of the files on the receiving side.